# How to add ArrayList of JButton on a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

I am coding a little game in which,in one class(named Brick) which extends JPannel,i have a JButton working as a "Brick" and in another class which extends JFrame i have an ArrayList of Brick named Grid which holds the Bricks.But i don't know how to represent the Bricks of ArrayList of Bricks in the serial form,i.e,one after the anoher,on the JFrame of Grid class.Please give me some suggestions.
**EDIT :** I also want no space between the two buttons.How can i stick two buttons,sharing boundaries?

Comment: @nachokk Is `GridBagLayout` class is helpful here?Should i read that class for this problem?

Comment: Yep GridBagLayout is a powerful, but perhaps you only need a GridLayout or simple a FlowLayout

Answer (score 3):

You may use the following code snippet to add and array of customized classes of JButton.
You may edit it as per your needs.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * A JList of JButtons.
 */
public class JButtonListDemo implements Runnable
{
  private JList jlist;

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new JButtonListDemo());
  }

  public void run()
  {
    Object[] items = new ButtonItem[] {
        new ButtonItem("Apple"),
        new ButtonItem("Banana"),
        new ButtonItem("Carrot"),
        new ButtonItem("Date"),
        new ButtonItem("Eggplant"),
        new ButtonItem("Fig"),
        new ButtonItem("Guava"),
    };

    jlist = new JList(items);
    jlist.setCellRenderer(new ButtonListRenderer());
    jlist.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    jlist.setVisibleRowCount(5);
    jlist.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {
      @Override
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event)
      {
        clickButtonAt(event.getPoint());
      }
    });

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(jlist));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  private void clickButtonAt(Point point)
  {
    int index = jlist.locationToIndex(point);
    ButtonItem item = (ButtonItem) jlist.getModel().getElementAt(index);
    item.getButton().doClick();
//    jlist.repaint(jlist.getCellBounds(index, index));
  }

  public class ButtonItem
  {
    private JButton button;

    public ButtonItem(String name)
    {
      this.button = new JButton(name);
      button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
      {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
          System.out.println(button.getText() + " was clicked.");
        }
      });
    }

    public JButton getButton()
    {
      return button;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
      return button.getText();
    }
  }

  class ButtonListRenderer extends JButton implements ListCellRenderer
  {
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList comp, Object value, int index,
                                              boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus)
    {
      setEnabled(comp.isEnabled());
      setFont(comp.getFont());
      setText(value.toString());

      if (isSelected)
      {
        setBackground(comp.getSelectionBackground());
        setForeground(comp.getSelectionForeground());
      }
      else
      {    
        setBackground(comp.getBackground());
        setForeground(comp.getForeground());
      }

      return this;
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could always layout your JButtons vertically on a JPanel (using a new GridLayout(0,1) perhaps) and then put your JPanel in a JScrollPane, thus mocking a JList of JButtons.

Comment: Can i do it with GridBagLayout?

Comment: yes any layout supporting the jlist will also support the buttonlist